# Regex group string replace issue

Tags: c#, regex

The target string is `"A + A_RT + B*A+AA"`. I want to replace `A` with `B` and `B` with `A`. But I don't want to replace `A_RT` to `B_RT` or `AA` to `BB`. The expected result is `"B + A_RT + A*B+AA"`. How can I do this in C#? Thanks.

Currently I use the following codes, but it will replace `A_RT` to `B_RT`...

```
IDictionary<string, string> map = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                                  {
                                      {"A","B"},
                                      {"B","A"},
                                  };

string str = "A + A_RT + B*A+AA";
var regex = new Regex(String.Join("|", map.Keys));
var newStr = regex.Replace(str, m => map[m.Value]);
```

Comment: You need to use look behind and look ahead to check whether there is any valid character for a name.

Comment: Append (?<!\w) before and (?!\w) after the regex to see whether it works or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the regex to `var regex = new Regex(@"\bA\b|\bB\b")`, then it can work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not particularly good at regex patterns, so there is probably a better way to do this. But the pattern

```
@"([a-zA-Z_]+)"
```

was able to grab all your variable tokens as match results.

Answer (score 0):

Use `var regex = new Regex(String.Format("\\b[{0}]\\b",String.Join("", map.Keys)));`